# Make a moving platform in java

Tags: java

I have tried many different things, but I just cant get this to work. I want to make a moving platform, that moves slowly left to right and then right to left. I got the left to right part, but not the right to left. Here is what I use for left to right :

```
public int centerX = 650;
public int centerY = 382;

private int speedX  = 2;


    if(centerX + speedX >= 765){
        centerX = 650;
        speedX = -2;
    }else{
        centerX += speedX;
    }
```

This makes the platform go back to the beginning , directly. Why ? How and what can I add to make it go back slowly ?

Comment: inb4 Thor's hammer closes Thor's question.

Comment: `why? => centerX = 650`

Comment: It's hard to tell without more of your code. This isn't enough to figure it out. After it jumps back to 650, does it start going right or left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop you assign centerX back to 650, that's what causes it to jump back.

Just set the speed to -2 and then also have a check for it going less than 650 and if it does set it back to +2

The platform should then bounce backwards and forwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't see the centerX =650 line.